# Quickbooks Refresh Token in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using the Azure Data Factory integration with Quickbooks, the refresh token expires in 24 hours. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attempted this first using parameterized linked service for Quickbooks. However it did not seem there was support for asking for those parameters when copying the data in flow. I was able to solve this instead by using Azure Key Vault to store the secret and refresh token for linked service. Then I created a pipeline with web activity to first get current secret from vault -> web activity to get new refresh token from Intuit -> web activity to set secret in key vault. That way the Quickbooks linked service will always find the latest from key vault.

My pipeline looks a follows:
[ADF Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADkC8.png)

Comment: I tried this approach but had some issues with this approach failing periodically. I ultimately ended up using a 3rd party tool called Skyvia to dump my QuickBooks data to a SQL Server periodically - it does incremental loads, so it was very efficient. I'm going to mark this as the answer, though, as I think it is the right way to do it with ADF, and I am assuming what I hit may have been transient errors.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Each day(every 24 hours), QuickBooks Online will return a new Refresh Token for every Refresh Token API call. Which means if a new refresh token is returned, the previous one will be forced to expire. For more info please refer to below posts:

https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D50f000051WZUGCA4/refresh-token-is-expiring-each-day-instead-of-lasting-100-days

https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/article/Validity-of-Refresh-Token

If you would want to update the Refresh token for every ADF pipeline run, then you may have to have another process or a web activity to get the Updated/latest refresh token using QuickBooks/Intuit REST API's and parameterize the refresh token and access token fields in Quickbooks linked service. By parameterizing the Quickbook linked service, you can get the latest access and refresh token using web activity in ADD and pass those values to the subsequent activity where Quickbooks connector is being using.

To explore about parameterizing your linked service, please refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services?tabs=data-factory